# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT QuoteReference,
       CreatedDate,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       Operation,
       TableName,
       OccurredAt,
       PerformedBy,
       FieldName,
       OldValue,
       NewValue,
       Quotes.CreatedByID,
       CompletedDate,
       EmailAddress = (SELECT ContactDetails.EmailAddress,
                              QuoteReference,
                              ContactDetails.MobilePhoneNumber
                       FROM   ContactDetails,
                              Quotes,
                              QuoteCustomers
                       WHERE  ContactDetails.ID = Quotes.ID
                              AND QuoteCustomers.QuoteID = ContactDetails.ID)
FROM   Quotes
       JOIN Audit
         ON Quotes.ID = Audit.RowId
WHERE  Quotes.CreatedDate BETWEEN '20100401' AND '20120830'
       AND PaymentReference IS NOT NULL
       AND Audit.OccurredAt > Quotes.CompletedDate
       AND Quotes.EmailAddress < > NULL
       AND TableName = 'Quotes'
       AND Quotes.PolicyReference = NULL
       AND Quotes.CreatedByID < > 2 
ORDER BY  Audit.OccurredAt desc
```

I get this error when executing:

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

After adding the second where clause in the subquery. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you selecting `QuoteReference,ContactDetails.MobilePhoneNumber` in the subquery? You just need `EmailAddress` as you are assigning it to a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting three columns values into one variable.

Change

```
EmailAddress = (SELECT EmailAddress,
                          QuoteReference,
                          ContactDetails.MobilePhoneNumber
                   FROM   ContactDetails,
                          Quotes,
                          QuoteCustomers
                   WHERE  ContactDetails.ID = Quotes.ID
                          AND QuoteCustomers.QuoteID = ContactDetails.ID)
```

to

```
EmailAddress = (SELECT EmailAddress
                   FROM   ContactDetails,
                          Quotes,
                          QuoteCustomers
                   WHERE  ContactDetails.ID = Quotes.ID
                          AND QuoteCustomers.QuoteID = ContactDetails.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery have to return ONE row and ONE column so it should looks like:

```
   EmailAddress = (SELECT TOP 1 ContactDetails.EmailAddress
                   FROM   ContactDetails,
                          Quotes,
                          QuoteCustomers
                   WHERE  ContactDetails.ID = Quotes.ID
                          AND QuoteCustomers.QuoteID = ContactDetails.ID)
```